# How to migrate data from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.3-p1 without using the Migration tool?

Tags: import, migration, export

We had 3 stores in Magento 1.9.4. I migrated 2 of them to Magento 2.4.2-p1 using the Magento Migration tool, installed the Smartwave Porto theme and the Amasty extensions and now we have many many problems!

Here is what I would like to do:

- make a fresh install of Magento 2.4.3-p1
- install the Smartwave Porto theme
- install the Amasty extensions

and then:

- **export customers, orders and products from our Magento 1.9.4** (for the 1 store we didn't migrate to our Magento 2.4.2-p1) **and import it into this Magento 2.4.3-p1 installation WITHOUT using the Magento Migration Tool** (*as I believe doing that messed up our Magento 2.4.2-p1*).

**How can this be done?**

***Also - if this test will work, what would be the best way to move customers, orders and products from the broken Magento 2.4.2-p1 to the new Magento 2.4.3-p1?***

---

UPDATED on March 5th, 2022:

What Ankit said in his comment is exactly what we are experiencing - *a lot of problems and it has to do with our multi-website/store set up* (such as double/triple authorizations in all Payment systems, website getting stuck when placing orders etc.). **I would ideally prefer to do an Export from Magento 1.9.4 and then Import into the latest version of Magento** rather than doing a Migration as that seems to break things. **If this is not possible, can you recommend a Migration Tool that works?**

Comment: It does have many problem specially when you have multi stores website, but without migration tool it will be hectic thing you can use another extension for migration available in the market.

Comment: @Ankit Thank you for your answer. I think you make a good suggestion - what other Migration Tool do you recommend? Is there any way to do an actual Export and then Import rather than doing a 'migration'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to help you as you ask for migration extensions:

https://litextension.com/shopping-cart-migration/magento-1-to-magento-2-migration.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=migration

https://www.dckap.com/blog/how-to-migrate-magento-1-9-to-2-3-without-any-issues/

As I told you it would me more hectic if you don't use migration tool but if you want I think you can follow below steps:

1. Export all entities from M1.
2. Create stores and website
   according to M1 in your new installation of M2.
3. Create and
   modify DB tables(core M2 tables also if required) and create
   attributes and note there IDs.(In M2).
4. Modify CSV according to M2(you can download sample CSV from Import tab). Also, change all attributes IDs and store IDs accordingly.

But believe me Allysin without migration tool it will me more hectic.

Answer (score 0):

**Use below paid extension**

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-extensions-2-x/magento-2-data-migration-pro/

(Stack note:: I know 3rd party url is not good in ans but I have to do)